# Why does my Debian 11 stop on the bootscreen?

Tags: debian, boot

When I boot on Debian 11 on VMware, it stops at the boot screen where it displays :

[image]

I don't understand because it worked before. I think the problem appeared after I did an `apt upgrade` but I'm not sure if it's correlated...

VMware is up-to-date.

Anyone knows what is happening and how to solve it ?

Thx!

Comment: Try to boot the kernel you had before. Grub should let you choose it. Does it work?

Comment: Woah it works thx ! I switched from the 5.10.0-13-arm64 to 5.10.0-11-arm64. I guess VMware can't work with the new kernel version. Do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you try editing the kernel boot line (pressing `e` in GRUB) to remove any `splash=silent` or `quiet` parameters? Also: How long did you wait for messages to appear?